# Django and python - different versions

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7, virtualenv

I've an application running quite a long time ago with python 2.6.6 and Django 1.4.5. It' s running on apache2 and Debian (of course it uses virtualenv).

I' d like to add another application to that server, but with python 3.4.5 and Django 1.9(+).

They'd have of course a different virtualenvironment, even a different domain, however, I' d like them to use the same DB.

My question would what kind of complications will I face? For instance different table layout for Django tables, no south anymore, but migrate, etc. Are these problems even overcomeable?

Thanks.

Comment: I would not recommend to have same database for two applications. on top of that having two different django(means different orm behaviors), i would say it might become disastrous. Maybe consider building an restful api service from on Project and consume it another.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, assume application #1 is the python 2.6.6 + django 1.4 app
      assume application #2 is the python 3.4 + django 1.9 app

These problems are 100% overcomeable, it just that application #2 (the one with python 3.4.5) will have to treat application #1's database as unmanaged.  You can create the unmanaged models you'd need from application #1's database by using the `inspectdb` command.  Good luck!